# JQuery Validation Engine criteria dynamically changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

On my website the amount value is based on user's Radio Button choice.

Users can also enter a bigger amount than the one proposed, so the minimum amount has to be dynamically checked.

With JQuery Validation Engine, I would like to set this value:

> integer[min[**xx**]]

Here is the code:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('#id1').click(function(){      
      document.getElementById('amount').value = 50;
   });        
   $('#id2').click(function(){      
      document.getElementById('amount').value = 17;
   });      
 });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<label class='label-radio'>
  <input type='radio' name='invoice' id='id1' value='id1'>
  Choice 1
</label>

<label class='label-radio'>
  <input type='radio' name='invoice' id='id2' value='id2'>
  Choice 2
</label>

<label for='amount'>Amount
  <input id='amount' name='amount' type='text' class='validate[required,integer[min[xx]]]'>
</label>
```

You can see a basic pattern of the source code here: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Jibeji/pen/geLBxd)

Is it possible to do this with JQuery?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to add dynamic rule, you can see working example here 
https://jsfiddle.net/dipmala/x163rbwk/15/

**HTML Code**

```
<form name="myForm">
<label class='label-radio'>
<input type='radio' name='invoice' id='id1' class='radioclick' data-val='50' value='id1'>
Choice 1
</label>
<label class='label-radio'>
<input type='radio' name='invoice' id='id2' class='radioclick' data-val='17' value='id2'>
Choice 2
</label>
<label for='amount'>Amount
<input id='amount' name='amount' type='text' >
<input type="submit">

</form>
```

**Javascript code**

```
$("form").validate({
rules: {
    amount: {required: true, min: 1}
  }   });

 $('.radioclick').click(function(){      
  var mx = parseInt($(this).attr("data-val"));
   $("#amount").rules("add", {
   min: mx
  });  
 });
```

Comment: dipmala, are you this works with posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine ?

Comment: Yes check working demo here you can see jquery validation plugin is included. https://jsfiddle.net/dipmala/x163rbwk/15/

Comment: dipmala, I am using https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine not jquery validation plugin. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a better/cleaner way, but it works:

**Javascript code**

```
var $total;

jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
   $(function() {
      var $signupForm = $( '#PaypalDiv' );
      $signupForm.validationEngine();
   });

   $('#id1').click(function(){
      $total= 50;
      document.getElementById('amount').value = $total;
   });        
   $('#id2').click(function(){
      $total = 17;
      document.getElementById('amount').value = $total;
   });      
});

function check_min(field, options){
   if(parseFloat(field.val()) < $total ){
      return "Cannot be lower than "+$total;
   }
}
```

**HTML code**

```
<form action='#' method='post' id='PaypalDiv'>
   <label class='label-radio'>
     <input type='radio' name='invoice' id='id1' value='id1'>
     Choice 1
   </label>

   <label class='label-radio'>
     <input type='radio' name='invoice' id='id2' value='id2'>
     Choice 2
   </label>

   <label for='amount'>Amount
     <input id='amount' name='amount' type='text' class='validate[required,custom[number],funcCall[check_min[amount]]]'>
   </label>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```